# HTML FORM INCREASE BUTTON

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to increase my form button size because it's small and how can i do it?

my code is:

```
<form action="./sotto/sotto.html">
    <input type="submit" value="TRACKLIST ->" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**CSS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to change the dimensions for your HTML input button.

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form action="./sotto/sotto.html">
    <input type="submit" value="TRACKLIST ->" />
</form>
```